# php array to json sting conversion

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi every one i am pretty new to programming and my worry is as follows.
 I have the following php code where students' averages are calculated and the result filled in an asssociative array. This array should later on be converted to json format.

```
    require_once("functions.inc"); // all my functions are here

   $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB); // connects to my database
if (!$conn) {
error_log("Cannot connect to MySQL: " .$mysqli->connect_error);
return false;
}

         $query = "SELECT distinct exam.student_matricule from exam join student on exam.student_matricule=student.student_matricule where student.class_id=3"; //
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
           if(false===$result)
           {    
              printf("error: %s \n",mysqli_error($conn));
           }

           while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) 
           {
            $studentmatricule = $row['student_matricule'];

            $average=student_average(3,$studentmatricule,1); // this function call calculates students' averages

            $stud_averages[$studentmatricule]=$average; //associative array that has **$studentmatricule** as key and **$average** as value

          }

           foreach($stud_averages as $student => $av)
           {
            $data=array('student_matricule'=>"$student",'average'=>"$av");
            print json_encode($data);
           }
```

My worry now is, **print json_encode($data)** prints

**{"student_matricule":"17A002NA","average":"12.52"}{"student_matricule":"17A001NA","average":"10.53"}{"student_matricule":"17A003NA","average":"12.69"}**

But i want something like

**[{"student_matricule":"17A002NA","average":"12.52"},{"student_matricule":"17A001NA","average":"10.53"},{"student_matricule":"17A003NA","average":"12.69"}]**

Please what should i do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's pretty inefficient. You first loop the db results, pushing everything in an array, then you loop that array creating in new array with the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing single dimensional Array inside loop so it is printing as a JSON

If you want it as a JSON array you need to store it in a multidimensional array  like this

```
$data = [];
foreach($stud_averages as $student => $av)
{
   $data[]=array('student_matricule'=>"$student",'average'=>"$av");
}
print json_encode($data); // It prints JSON Array
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing every array seperately in foreach loop. You need to add every loop data in a array that defined outside the loop. You can try like this :

```
$res = array();
foreach($stud_averages as $student => $av)
{
    $data=array('student_matricule'=>"$student",'average'=>"$av");
    array_push($res, $data);
}
print json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this

```
$data = [];
$std = array();
foreach($stud_averages as $student => $av)
{
   $std['student_matricule']= "$student";
   $std['average'] ="$av";
}
 array_push($data,$std);
print json_encode($data); // It prints JSON Array
```